# Can't save instance of a form on database. Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I trying to write a small app while learning django. I was trying to create a django form to create an instance of one of my models in database. I was following [youtube django guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfjhLKL-_5Q&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzRcd-q4vR5qAgOZUuz8041S&index=14) to accomplish this. I wrote similar code, but the program doesn't seem to save created model in database.

this is my models code:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class VoteType(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Vote(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to= "images/vote/")
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    vote_type = models.ForeignKey(VoteType)
    vote_type.null = True

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

this is my views code for create:

```
def create(request):
    form = VoteTypeForm(request.POST or None)
    print request
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    print instance
    print instance.name

    instance.save
    print instance.pub_date
    context = RequestContext(request,{
            'form': form,
    })
    return render(request, 'Vote/create.html', context)
```

this is my create.html

```
<form method = 'POST' action = ''>{%csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type = 'submit' value="create"/>
</form>
```

and this is urls(just in case):

```
urlpatterns = [
    #url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    #url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/voting/$', views.voting, name='voting'),
    url(r'^create/$', views.create, name='create'),
]
```

I don't get whats wrong with the code. When I go to page, type in data and click button create, it prints the data name and data pub_date. when I go to python console and type VoteType.objects.all() it doesn't show my newly created data there.

Comment: I'm not sure why you wrote this: `vote_type.null = True`? If this is from the tutorial, stop using it and use the [official guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/).

Comment: its not from tutorial, I did that because database was asking me for default value so I made the field nullable. I know its better to write vote_type = models.ForeignKey(VoteType, null = True) I just didn't fix it yet. thx for comment. also I already did the official guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quite a few problems with your view.

Firstly, you never call `is_valid()`, so you don't check that the form actually validates.

The main problem though is that you never call the save method: you only reference it. I'm not sure why you use `commit=False` in the form save in the first place, but having done so you need to do `instance.save()` to actually save it to the db. It would be easier just to do `form.save()` in the first place, though.

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling the method save for the instance object.

Change `instance.save` to `instance.save()`